# Limits of integration bounds when applying integration by substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, substitution

In the context of probability theory, density functions and distribution functions I stumbled upon the following.

Let's assume that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijective continuously differentiable function. We want to show that
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(g^{-1}(y))(g^{-1}(y))'dy=1.
$$
First, we start with integration by substitution, where $x:=g^{-1}(y)$. We define the preimages by $b:=g^{-1}(\beta)$ and $a:=g^{-1}(\alpha)$ and get
$$
\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(g^{-1}(y))(g^{-1}(y))'dx.
$$
Now, letting $\beta\to\infty$ and $\alpha\to-\infty$ I am not sure how to correctly argue that this implies $a\to-\infty$ and $b\to\infty$. Intuitively, it makes sense because by letting $\beta\to\infty$ and $\alpha\to-\infty$  I cover the whole image set of $g$. This means that I need to gather all the preimages/the whole domain of $g$ which is $\mathbb{R}$ or in other words $(-\infty,\infty)$. But this sounds very sloppy. Do you have any suggestions to make this a bit more formal?

Comment: the point is that $g$ is bijective. Since g is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$, and g is monotone, it follows from $g(b)\to \infty$, that $b\to \infty$

Comment: @Fix Ah ok. So the formal reasoning would be: because of $g′\neq0$ we have strict monotonicity (increasing or decreasing). If we assume strictly increasing monotonicity and use continuity of $g$, then we get $g(b)\to \infty$, correct?

Comment: yes, either g is globally decreasing or increasing. The reasoning for that, however, is not that $g'\neq 0$, we don't know anything about g, but that g is bijective, and therefore monotone on any interval. The rest is correct

Comment: The thing is that $g'$ can be 0 (e.g. $g(x)=x^3$). Bijectivity+continuity on an interval implies monotony, I forgot to mention the continuity in my last comment :)

Comment: @Fix my bad, I thought that the derivative was non-vanishing, which is not the case. You are right.